# How to handle log(0) when using cross entropy

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning

In order to make the case simple and intuitive, I will using binary (0 and 1) classification for illustration.

**Loss function**

```
loss = np.multiply(np.log(predY), Y) + np.multiply((1 - Y), np.log(1 - predY)) #cross entropy
cost = -np.sum(loss)/m #num of examples in batch is m
```

**Probability of Y**

`predY` is computed using sigmoid and `logits` can be thought as the outcome of from a neural network before reaching the classification step

```
predY = sigmoid(logits) #binary case

def sigmoid(X):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-X))
```

**Problem**

Suppose we are running a feed-forward net.

> Inputs: [3, 5]: 3 is number of examples and 5 is feature size (fabricated data)
>
> Num of hidden units: 100 (only 1 hidden layer)
>
> Iterations: 10000

Such arrangement is set to overfit. When it's overfitting, we can perfectly predict the probability for the training examples; in other words, sigmoid outputs either 1 or 0, exact number because the exponential gets exploded. If this is the case, we would have **`np.log(0)` undefined**. How do you usually handle this issue?

Comment: For binary classification, does `Y` contain only the values 0 and 1?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't mind the dependency on scipy, you can use [`scipy.special.xlogy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.xlogy.html).  You would replace the expression

```
np.multiply(np.log(predY), Y) + np.multiply((1 - Y), np.log(1 - predY))
```

with

```
xlogy(Y, predY) + xlogy(1 - Y, 1 - predY)
```

If you expect `predY` to contain very small values, you might get better numerical results using [`scipy.special.xlog1py`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.xlog1py.html) in the second term:

```
xlogy(Y, predY) + xlog1py(1 - Y, -predY)
```

Alternatively, knowing that the values in `Y` are either 0 or 1, you can compute the cost in an entirely different way:

```
Yis1 = Y == 1
cost = -(np.log(predY[Yis1]).sum() + np.log(1 - predY[~Yis1]).sum())/m
```

Comment: In fact tensorflow does provide its own version of the function as `tf.math.xlogy`. Maybe it's new though and was not added at the time this answer was posted.

Answer (score 8):

> How do you usually handle this issue?

Add small number (something like 1e-15) to `predY` - this number doesn't make predictions much off, and it solves log(0) issue.

BTW if your algorithm outputs zeros and ones it might be useful to check the histogram of returned probabilities - when algorithm is so sure that something's happening it can be a sign of overfitting.

Answer (score 4):

One common way to deal with log(x) and `y / x` where x is always non-negative but can become 0 is to **add a small constant** (as written by Jakub).

You can also **clip the value** (e.g. `tf.clip_by_value` or [`np.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)).