# CNN algorithm predicts value of 1.0 and thus the cross-entropy cost function gives a divide by zero warning

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, cross-entropy

I am using CNN to do binary classification.

While the cross-entropy function is calculated by the code:

```
(-1 / m) * np.sum(np.multiply(Y, np.log(AL)) + np.multiply(1 - Y, np.log(1 - AL)))
```

when the algorithm predicts a value of 1.0, this cost function gives a divide by zero warning. How to deal with it? 
Or is there any way to avoid the prediction to become exactly 1.0, like any pre-processing skill?

When I use higher numerical precision, it works fine. But I am still curious about the warning.

Comment: Does the value of `m` become zero?

Comment: Where is the division by zero in that code? The only division is by m.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, `np.log(0)` generates the warning `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log`

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018625/how-to-handle-log0-when-using-cross-entropy

Answer (score 0):

This looks like try/except should handle the divide by zero error.

```
try:
    my_var = (-1 / m) * np.sum(np.multiply(Y, np.log(AL)) + np.multiply(1 - Y, np.log(1 - AL)))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("I tried to calculate the result, but I got a divide-by-zero error. Maybe you need to use higher precision.")
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [np.clip](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html). This bounds the elements of an nd array between a min and a max value.

```
epsilon = 1e-10
clipped_AL = np.clip(AL, epsilon, 1. - epsilon)
(-1 / m) * np.sum(np.multiply(Y, np.log(clipped_AL)) + np.multiply(1 - Y, np.log(clipped_AL)))
```